# How to solve "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'"

Tags: python, pandas, artificial-intelligence, attributeerror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3vXI.png)
Getting issues with my code unable to understand what to do next can anyone help me out

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, LSTM, SpatialDropout1D
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import pickle
import re

# Importing the dataset
filename = "MoviePlots.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding= 'unicode_escape')

# Keeping only the neccessary columns
data = data[['Plot']]

# Clean the data
data['Plot'] = data['Plot'].apply(lambda x: x.lower())
data['Plot'] = data['Plot'].apply((lambda x: re.sub('[^a-zA-z0-9\s]', '', x)))

# Create the tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5000, split=" ")
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data['Plot'].values)

# Save the tokenizer
with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(tokenizer, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# Create the sequences
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data['Plot'].values)
X = pad_sequences(X)

# Create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(5000, 256, input_length=X.shape[1]))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1)))
model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1))
model.add(LSTM(256, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(Dense(5000, activation='softmax'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.01), metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(X, X, epochs=100, batch_size=128, verbose=1)

# Saving the model
model.save('visioniser.h5')
```

This is my code and error in the image attached

Anyone please help me out solve this problem of my code please diagnose it

Comment: Show error messages and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: Before calling method `lower()` on object, add a check whether is the object if of type `str` (string) this should be able to move your forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the error is happening with `data['Plot'] = data['Plot'].apply(lambda x: x.lower())` (you are calling the `apply` function on a column of data -> one of the values in the column is not a string so it doesn't have the `lower` method)!

You could fix this by checking if the instance is actually of type string:

`data['Plot'] = data['Plot'].apply(lambda x: x.lower() if isinstance(x, str) else x)`

or instead of using a lambda function:

`data['Plot'] = data['Plot'].str.lower()` whereas `panda`´s `str.lower` skips values that are not strings!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your column `Plot` holds some `NaN` values (considered as `float` by pandas), hence the error. Try then to cast the column as `str` with [`pandas.Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) before calling [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) :

```
data['Plot'] = data['Plot'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.lower())
```

Or simply use [`pandas.Series.str.lower`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) :

```
data['Plot'] = data['Plot'].astype(str).str.lower()
```

The same goes with `re.sub`, you could use [`pandas.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) :

```
data['Plot'] = data['Plot'].astype(str).replace(r'[^a-zA-z0-9\s]', '', regex=True)
```